# Tomcat servlet mapping error 404

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Sorry if this is a common question, but I'm gonna crazy. 
I'm starting with JSP developing, using Tomcat running on Ubuntu Server. I'm trying to run my first "Hello World" servlet, without success.

I have the following stuff on the server:

- the `webapps` directory is: `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/`
- in `webapps` I have created the context-root `hello/` directory
- `hello/` contains `index.html` and `WEB-INF/`
- `WEB-INF` contains `web.xml` and `classes/HelloServlet.class`

This is `index.html`:

```
<html>
        <body>
                Click to request the HelloServlet.

                <form action = "/hello/helloworld" method = "get" >
                        <input type = "submit" value = "REQUEST" />
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

This is `WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/hello/helloworld</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and finally this is the source file of `HelloServlet`:

```
// HelloServlet.java, a simple Hello World servlet.

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter outputStream = response.getWriter();

                outputStream.println("<html>");

                outputStream.println("<head>");
                outputStream.println("<title>Hello, World!</title>");
                outputStream.println("</head>");

                outputStream.println("<body>");
                outputStream.println("Hello, world! This is my first servlet!");
                outputStream.println("</body>");

                outputStream.println("</html>");

                outputStream.close();
        }
}
```

The problem is that, on the client side, only `http://localhost/hello/` (i.e the `index.html` page) works. If I click the form-submit button, I get http 404 error (resource not available).

Probably there is an error in servlet-mapping, in the form and/or in `web.xml`, but I really need help to discover it.

Comment: Include the name of the package in the `<servlet-class>` tag ex. `org.firstservletapp.HelloServlet`

Answer (score 4):

```
<url-pattern>/hello/helloworld</url-pattern>
```

You should not include the context path in the servlet's URL pattern. It's already relative to the context root.

Get rid of it.

```
<url-pattern>/helloworld</url-pattern>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, writing HTML code in a servlet is a very bad practice. For that JSP should be used. See also [our own Servlets wiki page which contains sane Hello World examples](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get always a 404 error. Probably I will use JSP in a few time, thanks anyway for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Add context root to jsp action, below changes might work for you.

```
<form action = "/hello/hello/helloworld" method = "get" >
  <input type = "submit" value = "REQUEST" />
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get always a 404 error.

Comment: @ital Try with just `action="/helloworld"` after having changed your url-pattern to what BalusC said.

Answer (score 1):

404 may result of :

1. Bad mapping scenarios (you may have included extra context as answered above or misused wildcards schema)
2. The servlet has not started (see the startup logs stack in the console or catalina file, you should find your servlet fail exception trace)

Answer (score 0):

It took me ages to figure this out.  In my case I was getting 404s because I'd failed to appreciate that the Tomcat **URLs** are **case sensitive**!

e.g.:

```
http://server:8080/acme.MyPackage/DoStuff
```

...404!

```
http://server:8080/acme.myPackage/DoStuff
```

...Fine.

Madness.